# Remove all duplicate row in mysql and dont keep even one

Tags: mysql, sql

All I found was how to remove the duplicate from a table but keep one. What I want is how to remove all the duplicate and dont even keep one. for example

```
    name   +   lastname
   ____________________
    a      +   something
    a      +   something
    b      +   something
    c      +   something
```

become

```
    name   +   lastname
    ____________________
    b      +   something
    c      +   something
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Show the code you found earlier and then we'll build on it.

Comment: @Shahar for example this one which can select the distinct one. select distict name from table or delete from table where (select name from table having count(*) > 1)

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: hints, group by, having count :) try do it yourself 1st, post your query and we will fine tune it

Comment: This is actually really tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so from my experience with the database (such as the MySql), you just need this:
DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE name = "a" 
to delete all duplicated values that you see from the SELECT statement.

Based on my experience, there is no other way to remove duplicated rows automatically because MySql doesn't provide such mechanism (correct me if i'm wrong). However, MySql has mechanism to PREVENT duplicated rows to happen. This mechanism is called "**Primary Key**". Primary key ensure that the field in the table will not duplicated. For example when you create the table with the following statement:

> Create table SomeTable (
>    name varchar(50) ***primary key***,
>    lastname varchar(50)
>   )

You just say to MySql "Hey MySql, create this SomeTable with name and lastname fields. But for name field, make sure that there are no DUPLICATED values in the table!!". This means if the name field has "a" as a value ALREADY in the table, MySql will block and throw error for this following statement :
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES("a", "bla bla");
Why? simply because the the value "a" has already exist in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your information but if I do the same I still have one of those "a" which is duplicate. I need to remove any row which has a duplicate one.

Comment: hmm, the "Delete from" should sufficient if this is the case. Can you tell us more about the problem?